# Swift :- How to do the customize report for Crashlytics in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I'm new to the `Crashlytics` and I have just started using it after Google bought them (aka FirebaseCrashlytics SDK without Fabric). I have tried the documents and emailing Firebase on how to do the customize report, but didn't get an answer I was looking for. Also, the document `Crashlytics.sharedInstance()` don't have shareInstance popup when I type Crashlytics. **Here is one of the crashes I have and I would like to use the custom log to help me find out more about the crashes.**

[image: Crash report]

```
var sectionHeaderForSelectedDate: [ChartData] = [] //Section Headder
var cellInSectionForSelectedDate: [[ChartData]] = [] //Cell in section

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupScreen()
}

func setupScreen() {
    if sectionHeaderForSelectedDate[0].value[0].date.convertDateToString(dateFormat: .dayOfWeekMonthDayYear) != "" {
        self.title = "\(sectionHeaderForSelectedDate[0].value[0].date.convertDateToString(dateFormat: .dayOfWeekMonthDayYear)) Sums"
    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    for (index, metricItem) in sectionHeaderForSelectedDate.enumerated() {
        tableViewData.append(cellData(opended: false, title: metricItem.name,
                                      sectionData: cellInSectionForSelectedDate[index]))
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

According to me, the crash has happened in the `setupScreen()` and I would like to have a log to actually tell me if my `segue` from another `viewcontroller` is passing value to my variable (`sectionHeaderForSelectedDate` and `cellInSectionForSelectedDate`). How **do I do it and where should I put the code in the function?**

Thank you and please correct me if any of my comments about Crashlytics is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know Crashlytics has the beta version for the crash report with the correct syntax. I found it and tested it out it is working now! I used the debug example codes from Firebase to tested the report. Please check out the codes and the screenshots.

[FirebaseCrashlytics Customize Crash Report](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports-new-sdk?platform=ios)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false

    if isFromChatBot == true {
        showIntakeOptions()
    }

    let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 100, height: 30)
    button.setTitle("Crash", for: [])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.crashButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)

    Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCustomValue("\(isFromChatBot)", forKey: "viewdeloadTest")
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().log("viewdeloadTestForCrash")
}

@IBAction func crashButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCustomValue("test", forKey: "test1")
    Crashlytics.crashlytics().log("crashbuttonTapped")
    //Analytics.logEvent("Setup screen", parameters: nil)
    fatalError()
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's when you will need the good `FirebaseAnalytics`.

You can send logs in each of your necessary events, like so:

```
Analytics.logEvent("Setup screen", parameters: nil)
```

Make use of the `eventName`, and `parameters`.

After this, when the crash happens and you have a logged event before that, you will see this information in your **LOGS** tab.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I tried it out the code but it is not showing on the Logs. I followed the document with Crashlytics.crashlytics().log("loginfo") it is showing! But still thank you for answering :)